# CodeIgniter - Unable to access session in helper

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

This is really driving me mad. I have used this without any issues in the past.

So I have a Codeigniter installation, in which I have autoloaded session. I am also also autoloading a helper named "site" (site_helper.php).

Now in site_helper I do the following:

```
function checkLogin(){
  $ci = &get_instance();
  $session = $ci->session->user['id']; //this line throws errow
}

checkLogin();
```

What I get as result is:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined property: Welcome::$session
Filename: helpers/site_helper.php
Line Number: 15
```

If you are wondering what "welcome" is, its my default controller. This has worked well in other sites I have worked on. I am at a total loss what the issue is here.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [passing a session variable in a function to a helper in codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15182862/passing-a-session-variable-in-a-function-to-a-helper-in-codeigniter)

Comment: Is session library loaded ?

Comment: @Difster: No its not a duplicate because I am not passing anything to the helper.

Comment: @VincentDecaux yes its loaded correctly.

Comment: `= &`  should be `=&` not sure if that is the cause.. but.  `$ci = &get_instance();`

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried

Filename: **application/helpers/Site_helper.php** "First letter must all ways be upper case"

```
if ( ! function_exists('checkLogin'))
{
    protected $CI;

    function checkLogin(){
      $this->CI =& get_instance();

      $this->CI->load->library('session');

      // This only returns the id does not set it.
      return $this->CI->session->userdata('id'); 
    }

}
```

http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/ancillary_classes.html

Then on the controller

```
public function somefunction()
{
   $this->load->helper('site');

   // Test only
   echo checkLogin();
}
```

Make sure you have set your session save path I use the cache folder. This is the way I have set up mine. With folder permission 0700

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = APPPATH . 'cache/session/';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = TRUE;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ci->session->user['id'];
//replace with
$ci->session->userdata("session_variable_name");
```

If it doesn't work please follow below
Please check with your PHP version,
I have also faced the same issue and then I got to know that I was building the application in Codeigniter 2 and PHP 5.6 and I check with Codeigniter 2.0 and PHP 7.3 version I got this Issue. So I tried with PHP 5.6 version and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you might have forgotten to load the session library

```
    function checkLogin(){
      $ci = &get_instance();

      //load the session library
      $ci->load->library('session');

      $session = $ci->session->user['id']; //this line throws errow
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did knowing that I have a "logged_in" is the session key when authenticating in the Login.php controller

```
function isLoggedIn()
{
    $ci = &get_instance();
    $ci->load->library('session');
    $session =  $ci->session->userdata('logged_in');
    return (!empty($session))  ? true : false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make Sure you have auto load session libaray in autoload.php file

> Autoload.php
>   : $autoload['libraries'] = array('session');

For Accessing the session variable :

```
 $CI = & get_instance();
//or you can load library in the site helper also
 $CI->load->library('email');
 $data = $CI->session->all_userdata();
```

Add

> print_r($data)

. You will get useful results.